# Extjs 3.4.0, why can't I configure an Ext.Container with items?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I've been having trouble configuring Ext.Container and it's subclasses with items. I've been trying stuff like this:

```
var PanelSubclass = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    debugID: "DavidPanel",
    items: [{
        debugID: "DavidNumberField",
        xtype: "numberfield"
    }]
});
new PanelSubclass() //blows up
```

What I've figured out so far is that at initComponent time Ext.Container will call add(item) on itself for each of the configured items. For reference, here is the source for Ext.Container.add:

```
add : function(comp){
    this.initItems();
    var args = arguments.length > 1;
    if(args || Ext.isArray(comp)){
        var result = [];
        Ext.each(args ? arguments : comp, function(c){
            result.push(this.add(c));
        }, this);
        return result;
    }
    var c = this.lookupComponent(this.applyDefaults(comp));
    var index = this.items.length;
    if(this.fireEvent('beforeadd', this, c, index) !== false && this.onBeforeAdd(c) !== false){
        this.items.add(c);
        // *onAdded
        c.onAdded(this, index);
        this.onAdd(c);
        this.fireEvent('add', this, c, index);
    }
    return c;
}
```

The first line of this method calls initItems() which sets up a Container's internal items Ext.util.MixedCollection like so:

```
initItems : function(){
    if(!this.items){
        this.items = new Ext.util.MixedCollection(false, this.getComponentId);
        this.getLayout(); // initialize the layout
    }
}
```

So it looks like what's causing my problem is that I've specified an items in my configuration so the `if(!this.items)` check returns false and a true Ext.util.MixedCollection of items is never setup for my Container.

But that doesn't make any sense because you're supposed to be able to give a Container some items, and so I'm left wondering how on earth creating a container that contains anything ever manages to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that I got on the Sencha forums was this:

```
Ext.define('Foo', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.items = [];
        Foo.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});
```

I translated that to this solution using Ext.extend:

```
var PanelSubclass = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    debugID: "DavidPanel",
    initComponent: function(){
        this.items = [{
            debugID: "DavidNumberField",
            xtype: "numberfield"
        }];
        PanelSubclass.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
     }
 });
 new PanelSubclass();
```

Both of these will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you really search too far. Why are you looking all the way down to analyze the source code. Do it simply like the doc says. I never used extjs 3.4, I only used 4.2. That's why I cannot be very specific. In ExtJs 4.2 you would write :

```
Ext.define('Myapp.MyPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    debugID: "DavidPanel",
    items: [{
        debugID: "DavidNumberField",
        xtype: "numberfield"
    }]
});
Ext.create('Myapp.MyPanel');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the documentation for Extjs 3.4 it says that items is a valid config property to give to a Container. For the most part I find myself digging into the documentation when things don't work and the documentation isn't helpful. I don't know if things have gotten better in 4, but 3's documentation tends to be somewhat lousy.

Comment: Of course the items configuration is valid. It must work. This is not what I meant. What seems strange to me is that you extend a built-in class instead of defining your own, and that you instantiate it using new. At least in extjs 4.2 you must not use new, but Ext.create